# template argument 1 is invalid (Code::Blocks Win Vista) - i don't use templates

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have some troubles with my school project.

I have a class:

```
#include "Group.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class User{
    private :
        string username;
        vector<Group*> groups;
        void show() {
            for(int i=0; i<groups.size(); i++)
                cout << groups[i]->getName() << "\n";
        }
        string getUsername(){return username;}

};
```

and

```
#include "User.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Group{
    private :
        string name;
        string getName(){return name;};
        User *f;
        vector<User*> m;
        void show(){
            for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++)
                cout << m[i]->getUsername() << "\n";
        }
};
```

When I try compile it, it gives me errors:

```
E:\Group.h|31|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'User' with no type| E:\Group.h|31|error: expected ';' before '*' token|
E:\Group.h|33|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
E:\Group.h|33|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|33|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|36|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
E:\Group.h|36|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|36|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|47|error: 'User' has not been declared|
E:\Group.h|47|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
E:\Group.h|47|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|47|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|58|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'User' with no type| E:\Group.h|58|error: expected ';' before '*' token|
E:\Group.h|59|error: 'User' has not been declared|
E:\Group.h|60|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
E:\Group.h|60|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|60|error: template argument 2 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|61|error: 'User' was not declared in this scope|
E:\Group.h|61|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
E:\Group.h|61|error: template argument 2 is invalid| ||=== Build finished: 21 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

what's wrong?

It compiles only if I add `class User;` to Group.h file, and `class Group;` to User.h file but its not the point I’m looking for the right solution, not only the temporary one.

**MY WHOLE PROJECT:** http://www.speedyshare.com/jXYuM/proj.tar

Comment: `vector<Group*>` and "I don't use templates" don't go together.

Comment: Are these files named user.h and group.h, respectively? And they're including each other?

Comment: You're including User.h in Group.h and Group.h in User.h. That might blow up your code.

Comment: Moreover, you'll still have trouble trying to call a private method of User from Group.

Comment: If your teacher has taught you that coding style, ignore him in the future and get a good C++ book instead. Two most obvious no-go's: Missing include guards. `using namespace` in header files. I smell that the teacher also teached you `void main()` and `exit()` instead of return. Please don't.

Comment: @phresnel: relax it's just a simple code;) check out http://www.speedyshare.com/jXYuM/proj.tar and then say what yu think :P

Comment: @maxiz: No. "Purchase Premium or get Basic account for free" to download your project? Sorry. And even in simple code you shouldn't follow bad and frowned-upon practice.

Comment: @phresnel:you just need to click on proj.tar to download the file;)

Comment: @mazix: first observation: you should have removed the object and other binary files from the tar-file. second: `using std::cout` in presence of `using namespace std` is redundant. third: why `#include <cstdlib>`? fourth: inconsistent tabs vs. spaces

Comment: fifth: double-underscore-prefixes are reserved to C++ implementations (as well as single-underscore-followed by uppercase). sixth: again, no `using`-statements/directives in header files, bad practice, will cause name conflicts

Comment: @phresnel: thanks for your opinion, every opinion is priceless in getting to know better C++ :) I incuded <cstdlib> because I will need this later:)

Comment: seventh: your `get`-functions should be `const`. eight: you shouldn't return a vector of bare pointers. will the caller now be responsible for deleting them or not?

Comment: ninth: it is not clear what those string-parameters do in the user constructor. tenth: in your constructor, you are assigning instead of initiliazing. eleventh: your are not doing any manual resource management in your User-class, so your copy-assignment and copy-construction are redundant. Use the ones emitted by your compiler instead, this helps with maintainability.

Comment: @mazix: Never `#include` for "later". Only `#include` for _now_. There are too many zombie `#include` in the world already, wasting cycles and compilation performance.

Comment: twelvth: Your Group-class' behaviour might be undefined as you have non-void functions without return-statements. /// There is probably more, but that should be enough food for now. Final advice: Get a good introductory C++ book :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a cyclical dependency.  Both files need one another to compile.

Try forward-declaring User in group:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class User;

class Group{
    private :
        std::string name;
        std::string getName(){return name;};
        User *f;
        std::vector<User*> m;
        void show(); 
};
```

**Group.cpp**

```
#include "Group.h"
#include "User.h"

using namespace std;

class Group
{
    .....

    void show() {
        for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++)
        cout << m[i]->getUsername() << "\n";
    }

    .....
 }
```

Then in the Group.cpp file, include User.

You can forward declare in the header anytime the object size doesn't depend on  the actual size of the object your forward declaring.  In this case, (in Group) you use User as a pointer and therefore the size of Group is not dependent on the size of User it's only storing a pointer which is independent of the User size.

Another tidbit which should help is that it's bad practice to include namespaces (in your case std) in a header file.  You should remove the "using" statement and do std::vector instead.  Using a "using" in the cpp file is fine, as other code doesn't "include" your source.

Comment: You can't (just) forward-declare User as long as you're still referring to its methods (like `getUsername`) in the header file.

Comment: Yes, he would have to move that out to the cpp file.  Thanks.

Comment: @RC. : ok, i tried to do what you said but the problem isn't solved at all. Heres my whole project: http://www.speedyshare.com/jXYuM/proj.tar hope it helps you to help me:)

Comment: I can't look at your project at the moment, but a couple things you should look at.  You now do not include User in Group, so prior to the change any file that used User would have been fine if they had only included Group.  Make sure they include what they need and include User.h has well.  Also, your include files need to have guards.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @RC. : Ok, don't bother yourself, I think that I've already solved it: http://pastie.org/private/pal9nee940l4xxa6opmjq. Thank you so much for helping me! I really appreciate it:)

Comment: @RC. isn't it a `circular` dependency instead of `cyclical`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Answer (score 4):

You have a cyclic dependency in the headers. You could fix it by moving the implementations to `.cpp` files, and forward declaring the classes you use:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Group; // forward declaration

class User{
    private :
        std::string username;
        std::vector<Group*> groups;
        void show();
};
```

and

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class User; // forward declaration

class Group{
    private :
        std::string name;
        std::string getName(){return name;};
        User *f;
        std::vector<User*> m;
        void show();
};
```

Then, in your implementation files, you can include the headers.

Also note that you should avoid using `using namespace std` in headers and in large scopes.

Comment: It gives me: E:\User.cpp|27|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Group'| and E:\User.h|16|error: forward declaration of 'struct Group'|

Comment: @mazix that is because you are probably calling a method of Group, and that would be in a method not shown in your example (if you have removed the implementation).

Answer (score 2):

You *are* using templates. You're using `vector`, which is a template.

You're getting the error you do because the User class is not defined when you reach the following part of the code:

```
User *f;
vector<User*> m;
```

Why is it not defined - after all you're including the User.h header? Yes, but the User.h header also includes the Group.h header, so one of the two will have to be read before the other.

To fix this you need to change your headers, so that only one of them includes the other (or they both don't include the other). To do this you first need to move your method definitions into a c++ file, so that no method calls to the other class's method appear in the header. Then you can forward-declare the other class and remove the #include.